# Simplifying this summation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation

I've been doing this question and I'm stuck!

---

Each customer who enters Larry’s clothing store will, independently of every other customer, purchase a suit with probability p. Assume that N, the number of customers entering the store, is Poisson with parameter λ. Denote by $X$ the number of suits that Larry sells.

(a) Find $P[X = 0 | N = n]$, the conditional probability that Larry does not
sell any suit given that n customers enter his store, $n = 0, 1, 2,...$

(b) Deduce $P[X = 0]$

---

I'm fine with A, but I'm stuck on B.

For A)
$P[X=0|N=n] = (1-p)^n$

These are my workings for B)

$$P[X=0] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P[X=0|N=n]P[N=n]$$
$$\implies \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^n e^{- \lambda} \frac{{\lambda}^n}{n!}$$
$$= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^n  \frac{{\lambda}^n}{n!} $$
$$= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^n  \frac{{\lambda}^n}{n!}$$
$$= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{({(1-p)\lambda})^n}{n!}$$
How do I go on from here? The solution given is $e^{-{\lambda}p}$

Thank you!

Comment: **Hint:** Do you remember the Taylor series for $e^{x}$?

Comment: @AvZ I love you. Yes, of course! $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k!} = e^z$ and in our case, $z = (\lambda (1-p))$!

Comment: The distribution of $X$ is Poisson parameter $\lambda p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with probability distributions, so my answer is just about your computation.

There is a typo on the last line. It should be

$$e^{-\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{((1-p)\lambda}) ^n}{n!}.$$

And recall that

$$e^x=  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: This is correct! Thank you so much